# Ctrl-z in PowerShell not working! How I fix?

Tags: powershell

I don't know what's going on, but now, when I click ctrl + z in Windows PowerShell, it starts making a sound and I can't submit the command and exit the process. How I fix this?

Comment: It's doing something, the key combination itself seems to be working fine. What did you expect to happen when you pressed it?

Comment: The keyboard buffer is probably full. Try `ctrl + c` instead.